# Generar codigo aletaoriamente a un input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Que tal amigos como puedo hacer para generar un codigo aleatorio y que se muestre en un input(tendria que ser de 13 digitos) y que se pueda aplicar algun formato por ejemplo que siempre empieze en 7 es para codigo de barras y que este a su vez no se repita, y que siempre sea aleatorio.

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo !empty(form_error('codigo_barras')) ? 'has-error':'';?>">
    <label for="codigo_barras">Codigo de Barras:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo_barras" name="codigo_barras" required value="<?php echo set_value('codigo_barras');?>">
    <?php echo form_error("codigo_barras","<span class='help-block'>","</span>");?>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

Para generar una cadena aleatoria puedes crear una clase con el siguiente código:

```
 class tools{

    public function randomCode() {
                $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
                $pass = array();
                $pass[]="7"; 
                $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
                for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
                }
                return implode($pass); 
    }
}
```

Adicional a este código puedes hacer otra clase, para que haga una consulta a la base de datos (si es que guardas en base de datos este código, y así validar si ya existe, y si ya existe generar uno  nuevo).

Y bueno, para insertarlo en tu input pues podría ser así:

**formulario.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 

        require_once "tools.php";

        $instancia = new tools();
        $codigo = $instancia->randomCode();
     ?>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="codigo_barras">Codigo de Barras:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo_barras" name="codigo_barras" required value="<?php echo $codigo?>">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado sería este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trabajo en codeigniter tendria que adaptarlo al controlador

Comment: si, tendrías que adaptarlo, espero que te sirva, saludos.